# Implicit enumerated types (i.e. symbols) in SQL

Tags: sql, symbols, varchar, lookup-tables

We are often using VARCHARs for essentially enumerated values. I know it would often be smart to extract them into a separate lookup table and use an integer ID as a foreign key, but sometimes no other table is using it, and we don't want another JOIN, so we opt to keep them in the main table.

So, the question is, is there some DB feature that would allow me to mark such columns, and then use some internal lookup table to save space and improve performance of my queries? Something similar to Postgres' [ENUMs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/datatype-enum.html), but that would not require explicitly declaring possible values up front.

For example, I would want to do an INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO table (date, status) VALUES ('2011-01-25', 'pending');
```

and `'pending'` would be internally treated as an integer, keeping only one instance of the actual string, even if multiple rows contain the same value `'pending'`.

In some programming languages (LISP, Ruby), similar feature is called [symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_%28Lisp%29), de facto "named integers".

I'm mainly interested in Postgres and MySQL, but any other pointers would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle table compression and SQL Server page compression both do this, in addition to other tricks.  The nice thing about using inbuilt compression routines is that they are completely transparent - no extra joins are required in your code, and because there's less disk access, it is often quicker to access compressed than it is uncompressed.  I think Postgres does this as part of [TOAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html) when it uses the EXTERNAL storage strategy, but only on larger fields.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me the right keywords for further search! Transparency is just what I had in mind. And although page compression works on a bit lower level than I expected, the point is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question, but I've done it with functions and look up tables, or where speed is important, functions which just return a constant.

ie:

```
INSERT INTO
  table (date, status)
VALUES
  ('2011-01-25', udf_getConst('statuscode','pending'));
```

or

```
INSERT INTO
  table (date, status)
VALUES
  ('2011-01-25', udf_Const_StatusCode_Pending());
```

If you're using the constant in multiple places in a query, consider selecting it into a variable first.

You can also use bitwise logic for different status codes and store multiple values in a single integer column.

Comment: Thanks, this would be a cheaper version of what I am after. The UDF can perform an INSERT if the constant is not already in the dictionary. The problem is just that the logic in querying gets complicated, especially if the same table and column are used in many places.